# Render fire with transparency looks washed out

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fire, output

Why it is so complicated to render fire with transparency? A few versions ago, things wouldn't even show on the output file and now the render look very washed out compare to the Blender viewer, If I render it in EXR it look super bright and saturated.

Basically, I am asking… How can I match my output file to the output image on the Blender viewer?
Trying to create a fire spritesheet

[image]

**Update:**
You can see the results using external image editor vs Blender compositor, External editor gave me much better result.
I know you shouldn't render fire on transparency, but for my spritesheet this is necessary, and it looks like this way works pretty well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fire is never supposed to be rendered with transparency. You should render emission pass and add it to your image. Fire is plasma that emits light. Light sources(emission) need to be added to an image, not mixed. You will never get good results with transparency/alpha because this is not the right way to composite fire.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I am trying to create a fire spritesheet, so I assume I need a transparency... I will give the emission pass a go

Comment: Can you compose it together in Blender or you need to use an image editor?

Comment: Got a pretty good result using an image editor and adding the emission pass + alpha to the existing image, having to do it to every frame manually might be time-consuming, but it does give a decent result, so thanks.

Comment: You can use Color Mix node in Add mode in the Compositor to do that in Blender. You should not use alpha in any context here.

Comment: It should be flame on black background and it should be added to an image in "add" blending mode in linear color space without using any alpha or mask. Black parts of the image have 0 values, so when you add 0 to your image it doesn't change anyway.